# Changing CSS Margins for Printing

Tags: html, css

We have an element with a `page-wrapper` id. I have tested that changing the margin on this element does, in fact, remove the margin on the actual page:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #page-wrapper {
        position: inherit;
        margin: 0 0 0 220px;
    }
}
```

My goal is to keep the margin for the standard page, but remove it when printing, so I tried this:

```
@media print
{
    #page-wrapper 
    {
        margin: 0px !important;
        /*display: none !important;*/
    }
}
```

The `display:none` comment there is just to show that it does, in fact, hide that element for printing, it was there a part of my testing. However, the margin does not get changed like it should.

I am out of ideas on what I might be doing wrong, so I am hoping someone has an idea. We do NOT have any other `@media print` styles on the page, but do have other `@media min-width styles`, but as far as I know `#page-wrapper` should override them all for print.

Any ideas?

Edit: Setting `background-color:red;` doesn't seem to work as well, only hiding the element from view with `display: none` works.

Edit 2: I do set the `@media print` absolutely last in the stylesheet, not that it should matter since it's the only print style and uses `!important`, but still worth mentioning as one more thing to check off.

Edit 3: When inspecting the element, the only margin style applied is the style shown in the first code snippet. The `@media print`style does not show up at all when inspecting the element.

Comment: Sounds like you may have a margin applied with a larger specificity than the `(0,1,0,0)` calculated from the id `#page-wrapper` that also has `!important;`. See [this](http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) for more reference. Try opening the dev tools (`<F12>` in most browsers) and selecting the element to see the style breakdowns. Look for applied styles that may be more specific that contain the `!important;` tag in them as well. If you need help calculating the specificity, try [this](http://specificity.keegan.st/) resource.

Comment: Thanks, I just went through, and I am not seeing anything setting margin widths with important on the #page-wrapper. It's a premade stylesheet though, so there about 200 things marked as "!important" - will update after I go through all your suggestions carefully, ty.

Comment: Are you putting a media attribute on your main CSS link?  E.g., if you were to include your main CSS file with `media="screen"` then print styles might not work.

Comment: Mike, can you elaborate on that please? It doesn't apply if I have tested that the media print style DOES work when I just hide the elements, right? 
@War10ck I went to styles in console in the element - and the only place margin is being set is in the code snipper which I included. It's not even marked as !important.

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to tackle something similar, I created a PDF of the section of the page first and then I could print it if I wanted or I could email it instead. To adjust the margins for a PDF, you would use the `@page` selector. So, my embedded CSS would be:

```
@page{margin:120px 50px 80px 50px;}
```

It may or may not work as I haven't tried printing directly from the page, but that may offer another route to the same end goal.